# How to type a hidden solution?

Tags: support, markdown

In [this answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/1656) by Andrew the solutions to the two Chess problems are hidden and appear only when your mouse hovers over the answer box.

What is the markdown for that? I tried to enter the answer editor to see, but it is a `non-tag-wiki post on a meta site`, so I couldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a line hidden by prepending it with `>!` (note the space before any additional text).

Example:

`>! 1. e4 e5`

> 1. e4 e5

Comment: I made this answer community wiki so that you can edit it and view the source as well.