# Are problem solving questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, asking-questions

I'm pretty new to this site but I've been around the SE network for a while. I've always liked the [Programming puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site and I was thinking about doing here something that I've seen there for a while: a weekly challenge.

What I mean is posting a diagram asking for the best move in that particular position.

Are those kinds of questions allowed or would be closed as too broad?

EDIT: I've posted an example question: [Chess challenge #1: Mate in one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/chess-challenge-1-mate-in-one)

EDIT 2: As it seems that the question has been well received I'll keep posting challenges on a regular basis. I will post tactical and strategical challenges and I won't post another one of the same kind until the existing one has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the loop on this...

The question referenced in your first edit looks pretty good.  I posted an opinion about this a few years ago as well, and though the site has grown quite a bit since then, I think that the basic idea is still the same.

If it's a simple tactic that becomes obvious after you see the solution, without any redeeming qualities (i.e. nothing about the position makes it worthy of discussion), then it's probably not a good fit for the site.  As an example, an easy tactic from the lichess.org tactics trainer is probably too simplistic.

On the other hand, if a position creates discussion or has some novel idea (that would be worthy of discussion), then it's a better question.  The mate in one puzzle that you posted has some nice tries and the various pins are instructive IMO.

The previous discussion for reference: 
[What's the policy on brain teaser/puzzle questions on Chess.SE?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/whats-the-policy-on-brain-teaser-puzzle-questions-on-chess-se/60#60)

Comment: Whether a tactic becomes obvious after you have seen the solution depends entirely on the playing strength. And Adolfo's puzzles haven't sparked many discussions so far.

Comment: This is Chess SE not a tactics trainer site. I don't mind seeing the very occasional puzzle if it is genuinely interesting but not a puzzle of the day or even puzzle of the week.